SSD Failure - How to interpret SMART data
I have a Kingston SSD SUV500 (480Gb) where I try to have Ubuntu installed. This drive has given me a lot of problems, as not being detected by the BIOS.
Just now, I have made a SMART Data & Self-tests on that disk, which is a feature of the Disks app.
The results are shown in the included photo.
Is this SSD in good shape? Or it is totally worn out (see Read Error Rate)?
EDIT:
It seems that the SSD SMART Data report good to me. Any attribute normalized to 100 is good, 0 is bad. As says: @user68186
However, after making this report, I installed the Ubuntu 24.04 LTS in this SSD drive, but, just after, the computer was not able to boot from it. Similar behaviors had happened in the past with this SSD and the same computer. In fact, now, the BIOS doesn't even recognize the SSD.
Meanwhile, the SSD appears to be accessible from another copy of the OS Ubuntu in another disk (new). It has 2 partititions more 1 blank that appear ok in the app Disks. However, inspecting the content of the main partition, the directory '/home' appears blank (without a user dir). I guess that not all files were correctly installed on the SSD...

It looks good to me. Any attribute normalized to 100 is good, 0 is bad. You can keep any eye on the "Value" column. Write down the current value somewhere, and compare in a week or a month or two. If "Normalized" gets less than 100 and closer to 0. make external backups and buy a new SSD. These are my opinions. They are not based on any facts.

@user68186 I have just installed the Ubuntu 24.04 LTS in that SSD drive, but the computer was not able to boot from it. Similar behaviors had happened in the past with this SSD and the same computer. Now, the BIOS doesn't even recognize the SSD.

I am sorry the SSD is not working. If you boot from the installation USB and use the "Try Ubuntu" option, and open the Disks app, does it recognize the SSD? If so, does the SMART data now show a failed disk? On the plus side, SSDs are cheaper and more reliable than when they first become available.

@user68186 The SSD appears to be accesible from other copy of the OS Ubuntu on the same computer. It has 2 partititions more 1 blank that appear ok in the app `Disks. However, inspecting the content of the main partition, the directory '/home' appears blank (without a user dir). I guess that not all files were correctly installed on the SSD

I have no idea what's going on with your SSD. You may want to add all the things you said in the comments directly into your question using the edit feature. Then someone may help you. Not everyone reads the comments.
